# Apache Camel - Process Push Messages from TCP Server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, apache-camel

I have the following integration to be done using Apache Camel.

[image]

I have a TCP client which can communicate with a TCP server using JSON Protocol. And I have a legacy TCP Server, which uses **an outdated text based protocol**. The server protocol cannot be updated because some of it's services are still being consumed by other clients which support the outdated text based protocol mentioned above. So, I'm using a camel route to integrate this new client with the legacy TCP Server.

I have written the following route to convert messages.

```
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        String producerURL = "netty:tcp://<SERVER-IP>:<SERVER-PORT>";;
        String consumerURL = "netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:5050";;

        from(consumerURL)
                .process(new RequestToTXTProtocolProcessor())
                .to(producerURL)
                .process(new ResponseToJSONProtocolProcessor())
                .tracing();
    }
```

Now, the TCP Client can use the 5050 port to connect to the legacy server. When the new TCP Client sends a JSON request, the processor **RequestToTXTProtocolProcessor** converts the request to TXT protocol and sends it to the legacy server. Then, once the legacy server responds, the processor **ResponseToJSONProtocolProcessor** converts the TXT response to JSON and sends it to the relevant client. This message flow works fine with the following Camel Route.

But here's my issue.
The legacy server sends back **Push Message Notifications** to connected clients. But, none of my Message processors capture these push messages in order to do the protocol conversion. I have even enabled tracing to check message flows, but It seems Camel Route cannot see the push messages. But Anyway, the TCP/JSON Clients receive those push messages with the TXT Protocol.

What I need to do is, **convert the push messages protocol from TXT to JSON**

Here's what I've tried so far.

1. Tried using `netty:tcp://<SERVER-IP>:<SERVER-PORT>?clientMode=true` to connect the consumer as a client. The server sent push messages, but the clients couldn't get them.
2. Tried using `netty:tcp://<SERVER-IP>:<SERVER-PORT>?sync=false` to make the channel async, But still couldn't get the push messages to the Processors.

Link to Netty Component: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/netty-component.html

PS: I couldn't find a solution using camel for this problem. So, I implemented a processor, where it creates a TCP Client, and assigned it a unique identifier. I maintained 1 TCP Client per each TCP Session. I maintained a registry of TCP Sessions, and when the client receives a push response, I would look up for the session ID in the registry, and initiated a new Exchange using `ProducerTemplate` with the unique identifier put into properties. Later, I used another processor to map these exchanges with the correct TCP session and sent the push message to the relevant session. Hope this will help anyone who's stuck in similar issue.